# Visa question from USA to Dublin to Glasgow

Tags: visas, us-citizens, transit-visas, common-travel-area

I am a US citizen and I am flying from the USA to Glasgow with a stop in Dublin to change planes.

Do I need a visa even thought I am not leaving the plane and if so is it a certain type of visa?

Comment: I like the cows there.

Comment: You say at first that you are changing planes, then that you are not leaving the plane. Is this a stopover or a technical stop? Or, if you don't mind sharing, what is the flight number so we can look it up?

Comment: "to change planes" or "not leaving the plane" ... pick one ...

Comment: @brhans: Does it matter?  AFAIK US citizens don't need a visa to transit or even to visit Ireland.

Comment: @NateEldredge - only in the sense that a coherent question is more likely to attract a coherent answer.

Comment: I suspect that she meant "not leaving the airport" or something like that.

Answer (score 4):

Whether you leave the plane or not, US passport holders do not need a visa to transit in Ireland, nor even to visit.

https://www.dfa.ie/travel/visas/visas-for-ireland/